# Invalid header name angularJS

Tags: angularjs, header, angular-http-interceptors, custom-headers

I am trying to implement HTTPInterceptor to add custom headers in all out-going request to avoid duplicate post requests .

But I get the following error:

> Error: Invalid header name.

**Goal**

To avoid duplicate post request by adding unique request ids in all out going requests.

**What I tried**

I had already developed the interceptor to display loading and added the custom header in request section but was getting the same error , so tried to create one more factory for httprequestinterceptor which will add custom header .

```
angular.module('cinemaBooking').
factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function ($injector) {
      return {
        request: function (config) {    
      var generalService= $injector.get('generalService');
              config.headers['webReqId'] = 'BookingM-'+generalService.generateRandomID;
          return config;
        }
      };
    });
```

I need to add webReqId for all out-going post requests.

Thanks.

Comment: 'Error: Invalid header name.' is it a server side error?

Comment: Thanks Maksym  ,  it is a client side error -          Error: Invalid header name.
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeader@http://serverHOST:8080/portal/bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.js:18:14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `generalService.generateRandomID` is a function, 
if it is, you need to execute it:

```
...
  config.headers['webReqId'] = 'BookingM-'+generalService.generateRandomID(); //<--
...
```